# How to convert a text with accent to a utf-8 format?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to create a script that insert some rows in a table that has an xml saved as IMAGE type. The xml is using utf-8 format.

When I test with some text with accents, I just got the "illegal character" error on XML reading (via XmlDocument in c#).

So I want some way to convert an string with accent to a utf-8 format.

Example: when I save via XmlWriter (in c#) a string that contains "ã", it auto-converts it to "Ã£" to represent that character when saving on the database. And it works perfectly!
But I want to do it in a SQL Script.
So let's say the word "São Paulo", it saves "SÃ£o Paulo". But using only SQL Server (script), I just can't make the xml valid with the word "São Paulo".

Only for more tech details, I'm working with a specific varchar/nvarchar that has this problem, so I just need to convert an text to a "unicode" or "utf-8" text that is valid on xml reading. And using Oracle worked fine, as it saves with accent and reads normally (using BLOB type), but I need the same script on SQL Server too.

I already tried some collates, converts and casts that I've found on the web but nothing worked for me.

Anyone know anything I can do?

Note: a thousand of replaces is not a solution.

Comment: Why are you storing xml in a colum with the image datatype??? The image datatype has been deprecated since 2005. Why not use a better datatype for xml....like xml.

Comment: Its a legacy database. Do you think if I change the column type it will work?

Comment: Can you show the code in which `XmlWriter` writes `ã` as `Ã£`?  Because I can't reproduce that.

Comment: I am not going to recommend you just start changing datatypes of your columns without knowing more about your system. I would venture a guess that it will work but you may have invalid xml in there too.

Comment: In fact is not XmlWriter that is converting, but its when SQL Server saves the value on the IMAGE column.

Comment: I'll try to change the column data type. Maybe it works.

Comment: @dbc: The XmlWriter doesn't write ã as Ã£, it writes it as two bytes, which when decoded with some other encoding than UTF-8 becomes Ã£.

Comment: The classical way to encode such characters within XML is something like &amp; (meaning the semicolon) or &lt; (meaning the "less than" sign). Please give some more details about how you write and read this XML. Btw: I do not think, that the type of your column will help you here...

Comment: @IúridosAnjos: One more thing to point out: SQL Server stores XML in a fixed encoding allowing unicode. Your IMAGE is not aware of its content and therefore allows utf-8 encoding. You should make sure, that the storage AND your application deal with the same encoding. This will make things easier...

Comment: @dbc so there's some way that I can convert "ã" to 2 bytes the same as XmlWriter via SQL server commands? Do you know?

Comment: @IúridosAnjos, This is no "conversion", rather an erronous type out... You have to change this to the "utf8-save" method with &#1234; or &amp; or you must be sure, that both sides use the same encoding. Otherwise you will stick into troubles for ever...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
CREATE TABLE testXML(test XML);
GO
INSERT INTO testXML(test) VALUES ('<root><r>plain text</r></root>')
                                ,('<root><r>São Paulo</r></root>');
GO
SELECT x.y.query('.'), x.y.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM testXML
CROSS APPLY test.nodes('/root/r') AS x(y);
GO
DROP TABLE testXML;

/*
Result
<r>plain text</r>   plain text
<r>São Paulo</r>    São Paulo
*/
```

Here the same with IMAGE and a lot of casting around. delivers the same result:

```
    CREATE TABLE testXML(test IMAGE);
    GO
    INSERT INTO testXML(test) VALUES (CAST(CAST('<root><r>plain text</r></root>' AS XML) AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
                                    ,(CAST(CAST('<root><r>São Paulo</r></root>' AS XML) AS VARBINARY(MAX)));
    GO
    SELECT x.y.query('.'), x.y.value('.','varchar(max)')
    FROM testXML
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(CAST(test AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML)) AS tbl(x)
    CROSS APPLY tbl.x.nodes('/root/r') AS x(y);

GO
DROP TABLE testXML;
```